# How to run a x86 Linux VMware vm on Mac with Apple Silicon

Tags: linux, x86, arm, virtual-machine, vmware

I currently have a specific x86 VMware VM(example.vmwarevm) file, trying to run it on my Mac with M1 Pro

Any possible solution will be appreciated <3

I have tried UTM emulation, but it can't read vmx file

I also tried with docker, but haven't find any way to run VMware virtual machine  so far.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://askdifferent.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible.

As far as I know, x64 or x86 virtual machines can't run on Apple Silicon.

Rosetta only works for code, not entire VMs. You would need to emulate an entire x64 CPU. Rosetta doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes, so how can I emulate for a existed VMware vm, UTM can't do that

Comment: You could try QEMU, however I don't know about the exact instructions. But just try it out.